# Accessing a script on all objects with tag in Unity

Tags: c#, foreach, unity-game-engine

My question is simple, how to access my gameobjects custom C# script through a foreach.

I've tried following:

```
foreach(TowerController go in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tower")) {
        go.upgradeTowerProgress = false;    
    }
```

Doesn't seems to work. Dunno why, that's why im here to ask! xD

TowerController is my custom script on the gameObjects with tag Tower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work (untested):

```
foreach(GameObject go in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tower")) {
        go.GetComponent<TowerController>().upgradeTowerProgress = false;    
    }
```

What I changed is that you are iterating a GameObject array, so you need to do `foreach(GameObject go...`, then you use the [GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) function to get the component that is of the type `TowerController` and then you can access its `updateTowerProgress`. [THIS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html) page is always a good reference.

Comment: Awesome, i'll try that out asap! And be sure to let you know if it works :D